# Angular2 and Laravel CSRF protection

Tags: php, ajax, angular, laravel-5, csrf

I have already read some [topics](http://paulthorpe.co/blog/a-simple-api-between-angular-2-and-laravel)

And the problem I encountered is lies in this piece of code

```
<meta property="csrf-token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I'm using Angular2 as core engine, which sending AJAX requests to Laravel API and I'm not using blade templates - just `.html files`, so I can't call php function `csrf_token()` from html file

So, I added a temporary solution by extending my
/var/www/pandacrm/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( ! $request->is('api/*'))
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But it seems not the best way to work around, is there any other solutions to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can either disable the CSRF middleware (NOT RECOMMENDED) or provide the CSRF middleware with a valid token from your view. Making ajax requests without some kind of cross site request forgery protection is a very dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `meta` tag with `csrf-token` by using JavaScript in your html file!

**How to do this:**

Send an Ajax request to  Laravel Route to get token. (return `csrf-token` in a Controller action) And then create a meta tag with that token in your html file.

But before doing this, you have to disable csrf protection on that specific route.
There is a way to do this [here](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/disable-csrf-on-specific-routes) for laravel5 and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) for 5.3.

Now you have a meta tag with `csrf` that can be used for other ajax requests.