# Angular 8 and Laravel 5.4 Compatibility Inqiury

Tags: php, angular

My team and I are trying to make Angular 8 work in NGIX (PHP) server using Laravel 5.4 Framework. The key issue we’re having is that we cannot generate a csrf_token() in the Angular index.html since its an HTML page.

Is there a work around for this? Or a method to fenerate an index.php file in Angular?

Comment: here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219280/angular2-and-laravel-csrf-protection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 and Laravel CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219280/angular2-and-laravel-csrf-protection)